# Batch not working very well. IF EXIST

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, dos

Trying to play with some Batch.

```
@ echo off
IF EXIST %CD%\Minecraft.exe
Minecraft.exe
IF NOT exist %CD%\Minecraft.exe
wget.exe https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/Minecraft.exe
Minecraft.exe
pause
```

What have I done wrong? CMD just closes when I run it.

Comment: what is the value of %CD%. Echo %CD% and let us know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What have I done wrong?

You could read the help of the IF command `if /?`.

It explains that the if expects all on one line

```
@echo off
IF EXIST %CD%\Minecraft.exe Minecraft.exe
IF NOT exist %CD%\Minecraft.exe wget.exe https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/Minecraft.exe Minecraft.exe
pause
```

Or use the `ELSE`

```
@echo off
IF EXIST %CD%\Minecraft.exe (
  Minecraft.exe
) ELSE (
  wget.exe https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/Minecraft.exe Minecraft.exe
)
pause
```

Comment: That did it. Had to add a line after the download thought. Thank you.

Comment: Jack, since Jeb got it right for you, you should help him out and check his answer as correct in the upper right.